# why does scrollspy (bootstrap) allways jump to the last element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i tried to fix this issue, but all the advices in other threads didnt work.

My Scrollspy on the left is just not working and always jumping to the last item.

I have the div tag with this parameters:

```
<div id="content" data-offset="0" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#main-nav">
```

and the navigation looks like this:

```
<nav id="main-nav">
<ul class="nav">
<li class="active"><a href="#verein"><i class="icon-home"></i> Verein</a></li>
<li><a href="#training"><i class="icon-dashboard"></i> Training</a></li>
<li><a href="#team"><i class="icon-user"></i> Team</a></li>
<li><a href="#sport"><i class="icon-trophy"></i> Sport</a></li>
<li><a href="#kontakt"><i class="icon-comments"></i> Kontakt</a></li>
<li><a href="#sponsoren"><i class="icon-star"></i> Sponsoren</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9Lgx4/64/

Answer (score 0):

Works on Chrome, but not on Firefox O_o

To correct that, take this line :

```
<div id="content" data-offset="0" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#nav">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9Lgx4/92/

MartialE